# A _disk_id.pod file appears on a windows flash drive

Tags: windows, usb

What causes a   _disk_id.pod   file to appear on a windows flash drive, and is it advisable to remove it?

Comment: This appeared on my flash drive as well. What is it?

Comment: If this file was created by Windows Live Movie Maker, then you can remove it, as long as you are no longer using it with that software.  Incidentally, Microsoft has now discontinued Windows Live Movie Maker.  See:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054502/windows-10-movie-maker-is-no-longer-available-for-download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_disk_id.pod is created by Windows Live Movie Maker. I had accidentally changed my "choose default program ..." settings which was causing the video files to open with the Windows Live Movie Maker program. Even if you do not do anything with the video in the Movie Maker program or save anything in it the program will still create this file on the sd card.
PT

Answer (score 1):

For me I think the answer is _disk_id.pod belongs to media player software (in my case KMV).

I think it permits the software to identify a particular volume (in case you have saved playlists). The name kinda makes sense.

I have seen other explanations of .POD but none that make as much sense in this context (i.e. removable media).